# "application: not a procedure" while computing binomial

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket, pascals-triangle

I am defining a function `binomial(n k)` (aka Pascal's triangle) but am getting an error:

```
    application: not a procedure;
    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
    given: 1
    arguments...:
    2
```

I don't understand the error because I thought this defined my function:

```
    (define (binomial n k)
      (cond  ((or (= n 0) (= n k)) 1)
          (else (+ (binomial(n) (- k 1))(binomial(- n 1) (- k 1))))))
```

Comment: I should mention I'm using #lang scheme with Dr.Racket

Comment: I tried calling binomial(1 2)

Comment: what is `(binomial (n) (- k 1))` for a syntax? Try to remember the syntax for a variable in Scheme and compare with the use of `(n)`.

Comment: note that this algorithm is extraordinarily inefficient - _exponential_ number of recursive calls!

Comment: Please search for specific error messages on Stack Overflow _before_ posting the question.  (If you did, then please forgive me this comment.)  There are [other question about this error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22application%3A+not+a+procedure%22+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: possible duplicate of [“application: not a procedure” in binary arithmetic procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022704/application-not-a-procedure-in-binary-arithmetic-procedures)

Comment: oh, actually, it's more an error of [“application: not a procedure” in determinant code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18470443/1281433) where someone else tried to call a mathematical function by wrapping its argument list in parenthesis, which is _not_ the case with the question I already mentioned as a possible duplicate.

Comment: Btw, nowadays you should use `#lang racket` instead of `#lang scheme`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scheme (and Lisps in general), parentheses are placed before a procedure application and after the final argument to the procedure.  You've done this correctly in, e.g.,

```
(= n 0)
(= n k)
(- k 1)
(binomial(- n 1) (- k 1))
```

However, you've got an error in one of your *arguments* to one of your calls to `binomial`:

```
(define (binomial n k)
  (cond  ((or (= n 0) (= n k)) 1)
      (else (+ (binomial(n) (- k 1))(binomial(- n 1) (- k 1)))))) 
                        ***
```

Based on the syntax described above `(n)` is an application where `n` should evaluate to a procedure, and that procedure will be called with no arguments.  Of course, `n` here *actually* evaluates to an integer, which is not a procedure, and can't be called (hence “application: not a procedure”). You probably want to remove the parentheses around `n`:

```
(binomial n (- k 1))
```

It's also worth pointing out that Dr. Racket should have highlighted the same portion of code that I did above.  When I load your code and evaluate `(binomial 2 1)`, I get the following results in which `(n)` is highlighted:

[image: error in dr racket]

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
binomial(n)
```

`n` is an integer, not a function.  If you put parentheses around it like that, scheme tries to invoke an integer as a function, which naturally produces an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
 (define (binomial n k)
          (cond  ((or (= n 0) (= n k)) 1)
              (else (+ (binomial n (- k 1))(binomial(- n 1) (- k 1))))))
```

Problem is at here:

```
(binomial (n) (- k 1))
```