# Error in Racket/Lisp: expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Just a new defined arccos-function but I don't find the error:

```
(define (arccos z)
  (atan (
         (/
         (sqrt (-
               1 (expt (cos z) 2)))
         (cos z)))))
```

May you help me?
Error message:

```
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 1.1447765772467506
  arguments...: [none]
for (arccos 1)
```

Comment: Solved

One ( to much

here is the right code:
        (define (arccos z)
           (atan 
                 (/
                 (sqrt (-
                       1 (expt (cos z) 2)))
                 (cos z))))

Comment: I would recommend to indent the code correctly and then check the syntactical correctness.

Comment: When getting started with a lisp, the practical meaning of this error message is nearly always: "You have too many parens. Remember that `(` is not like `{`. If you don't have a function name after the `(`, you probably don't need the `(`." :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["application: not a procedure" while computing binomial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487959/application-not-a-procedure-while-computing-binomial)

Answer (score 2):

The error type is a common one - so here is how to quickly spot where the error is in a program.

Run it in DrRacket. Notice that this expression is colored red:

```
       (
         (/
          (sqrt (-
                 1 (expt (cos z) 2)))
          (cos z)))
```

The error message says: "expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments given". The last part implies that Racket expected `( ... )` to be an application of a procedure (function). However the first argument is : `(/ ...)` and the result of a division is a number.

That is: When you get this error always look at the first expression.

Here the problem is an extra layer of parentheses  `( (/ ...) )` should be `(/ ...)`. In other cases use display to print out the result of the first expression in order to see what went wrong.

Note: In can be helpful to use the following indentation convention when dealing with arithmetical operations:

```
(operation argument1
           argument2
           ...)
```

In this example:

```
  (atan (/ (sqrt (- 1
                    (expt (cos z) 2)))
           (cos z))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (arccos z)
  (atan (/ (sqrt (- 1 (expt (cos z) 2)))
           (cos z))))
```

There was an unnecessary pair of brackets after `atan`, also notice that correctly indenting will make this type of errors easier to spot.